# Render different from viewport preview

Tags: rendering

So I'm just starting with Blender, using a model found here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BzIQm-eK85EQeTJDOGVTVXhuUDA

In the viewport, I get something like this, which its OK for my needs:

[image]

However, when I render using Cycles, the result looks like this:

[image]

Which is clearly not of the same quality, even if it takes several seconds per frame on GPU. I tried checking every option under *Layer properties -> Passes* and *Filter*, but other than that I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Is the first image material or render mode? At least form the reflections it doesn't look like the same hdri is used (or any hdri at all) in the cycles render

Comment: @uvnoob The first image is in the 'layout' mode. I don't know how to activate HDRI in the cycles engine, sorry; but it that case it would mean that HRDI would be active for the 'preview' in the viewport and not for rendering?

Comment: I meant shading mode. "Layout" is a workspace. Shading mode is independent from workspace. If you want to preview your render, switch to 'render' shading mode. In any case, try setting up a HDRI and let us know if it helped. Here's a quick tutorial showing how to do it (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VBkj_I-ONk). You can use HDRIs from hdrihaven.com, or locate the default ones used by blender in your filesystem

Comment: OK, Ill try that, thanks. I am just learning blender fundamentals and I don't get why a quick preview seems of a better quality than the final render...

Comment: Again, I can't tell for sure but I think the first image is from material shading view, which would mean that it was rendered using eevee. If it's okay for your purposes you could switch your renderer to eevee - it is MUCH faster, although not as realistic and has it's own issues.
If you wish to render with cycles though, don't forget to enable denoising - this will eliminate the grainy texture on your renders. You can find numerous tutorials on how to get started with cycles on youtube.